# Is there a way to compare rows accross tables?

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a table A with VAR1 and VAR2. Suppose also, I have Table B with VAR1. Is there a way I can check to see if VAR1 from Table A is in Table B without merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merge it in some fashion, but certainly not with `merge`.  Depending on the characteristics of the two tables, you can use:

- Merge
- SQL Join
- Format lookup (load relevant parts of dataset B into a format)
- Hash lookup (load relevant parts of dataset B into hash table)
- Array lookup (load relevant parts of dataset B into temporary array)

And probably several other methods that I'm forgetting.